# Showing error when I use map function in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

In the React JS app I want to loop my state and return JSX

But when I use this showing the below error.

**State**

```
cart ={}
```

**in console**

[image]

**Code**

```
this.state.cart.map((item1)=>{
           console.log(item1)
       })
```

**error*

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.state.cart.map is not a function
```

Basically, I want the loop for below JSX

```
the title is Saree Blouse and Its quantity is 1
```

Comment: the `cart` array isn't valid, you should be seeing a syntax error. Please also make sure the example is a [mcve]

Comment: @evolutionxbox array syntax is perfect because when I put ```console.log(this.state.cart)``` showing the same result as I mention above

Comment: It's not perfect because there's a syntax error. - _"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ] after element list"_ --- If this isn't the issue, please update the example to show what the issue is.

Comment: Hey I update my question plz see once

Comment: You've replaced code with an image. This isn't helpful. --- I can see from the image however that `cart` is not an array, but an object. Object's don't have a `map` method. Use an array instead.

Comment: So how can I use an array instead of this

Comment: I don't know, as you haven't actually shown a runnable [mcve] yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `cart` to this:

```
cart = {}
```

and you can loop through it like this:

```
Object.values(this.state.cart) && Object.values(this.state.cart).map((item) => (
  <div>{`the title is ${item.title} and Its quantity is ${item.quantity}
`}</div>
));
```

Comment: why did you empty the `cart`?

Comment: I've add a check for `cart` in my answer, see it again @yuvraj

Comment: I declare the cart as empty and add data into it dynamically so it gets the same structure as shown in ScreenShot.

Comment: but what I'm trying to ask that the structure of the cart which I get is as I attach a screenshot in the question. But in your and cart structure is different than above

Comment: @yuvraj your `cart` is an `object` not an `array`

Comment: @yuvraj Did you get the answer? does it work for you?